# How to stow and go with the middle or 2nd row seats on 2017 Grand Caravan?

Tags: seat, caravan, grand-caravan

I bought a 2017 Dodge Minivan and I always thought that I should be able to stow away and go my 2nd row seats, but I tried to do that for the first time since I bought the minivan. I simply can't fold it and stow it away. Please take a look at the following pictures of my 2nd row seats. Am I thinking right when I say that this type of 2nd row seats can only be folded and/or removed ONLY. Can I stow and go these seats at all?

[image]

Comment: Not sure how you're trying to do this, but there should be panels in the floor just ahead of those seats. Lift them up, then plop the seats forward into the holes. I've rented a couple of the vans in the past and it was pretty easy. If it isn't easy, then it probably doesn't have it. Also, the hole where the seats go is pretty cavernous. I think the front seats may have to be up some before you try to lower them.

Comment: At second look, that's an entire bench seat, right? I'm pretty sure the stow-n-go has to be two separate seats (captains). Not sure yours is setup correctly.

Comment: Hi, Yea my seat is a bench. I did what you said and the whole seat came loose completely for me to remove it out of the van. No, it won't go into the space in the floor at all or fit into the space in the floor at all. The only thing I can do is fold the top half of the bench. I also moved the front seats all the way to make it easier on me to stow this bench but no go.

Comment: If you really need the "stow&go" then perhaps you can get the equivalent seats from a scrap yard (junk yard) and do the conversion. In your location this may need testing / certification to meet insurance requirements etc

Comment: @SolarMike no I am not looking to do that or interested but I just needed to know if this bench like seats suppose to be able to stow and go. I didn't realize at the time of the purchase. I just assumed all the seats and all vans came with this feature automatically for the 2nd row seats. I can easily stow away the last row of seats. If it can't be done, then it can't be done... Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you have the stow 'n go feature or you don't, and I can see that you don't. Not all Dodge/Chrysler vans have this premium feature. You really can't just change the seats because the whole floor system is different. Sorry there is no "fix" for this. Generally, if you have a 2nd row bench seat, then you don't have this feature. Though it's possible you could it for the 3rd row, but highly unlikely.

Comment: Well, I can stow away the third row seats... but not the second row bench. I even called the dealership and they told me the same thing that you said in your answer. Thank you.